# How to prevent OSX Yosemite from launching old app for ":news" URL in browser

Tags: macos, mail.app

I want to open a newsgroup url (eg. "news:comp.lang.python") in a browser, but my OS/X Yosemite (10.10.5) system insists on opening an old mailing application that is located inside one of my (external) backup disk.  I would like to change what it opens; ie. replace it with some mail software that is able to handle newsgroups.

It seems to be related to OS/X and not the browser because the behaviour is the same across the 3 browsers I tried it on (Safari, Firefox, Chrome).

Where does OS/X control the association done at the browser level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest method is probably to install [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) - freeware, old but still works well.
It installs as a Control Panel, from which you can define it in the Internet tab...

[image]

I don't have a specific Newsreader installed, so mine just says 'other' at the moment.

Comment: Do you know where this app gets its info?  A plist file somewhere perhaps?  On the system that has this problem Finder "Open with" dialog for a given file type lists a lot of applications OS/X found in external disks that contain backup of other computers.  I'd like to get rid of them too.

Comment: I used RCDefaultApp and it does work under OS/X 10.10.5 (Yosemite).  It did allow me to fix the association, Thanks!    It also lists all the invalid Apps that reside on external disks that should have never been identified by OS/X as applications that can be used.  Unfortunately RCDefaultApp does not seem to allow cleaning them out.

Comment: It's all controlled by [LaunchServices](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html) which is well beyond my ability to explain properly.

Comment: Thanks, looks like there is a lsregister utility that can be used to clean that up.

Comment: OK, after some digging around, I found a couple of sites describing how to use lsregister to clean up OS/X Default Application database. You first need to identify where that executable is.  It was not in my PATH. I found i t in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/

Comment: By closing all apps, rebooting, opening a shell and executing `lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user` then all invalid associations are gone.

Comment: Note that when you run the lsregister command, the system must have access to the disks that contain the old, invalid apps (if they are still in these disks).

Comment: One more snag: OS/X still adds the old apps to the list after rebooting with the disk where the old apps are located.  I tried the `lsregister -kill -r -f -domain local -domain system -domain user` command but as long as OSX sees the files, it adds them....